# Непонятно ведет себя запрос sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица с строковыми полями `fam`,`nam`,`snam`

делаю запрос

```
select fam,substr(nam,1,1)+"."+substr(snam,1,1) as io
```

на выходе дает поле `io` в числовом виде. Хотя по идее должна быть строка?

в чем проблема?

Comment: Оператор `+` складывает числа и даёт число, используйте `||` (хз почему, но [говорят что так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415))

Comment: в sqlite нет строгой типизации, так что любые данные перед применением математических операторов преобразуются в `NUMERIC`.